# Rails:Carrierwave previously stored files are being replaced by newer ones in multiple image upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, upload, carrierwave

I'm following the instructions in the carrierwave documentation but my problem is that when I upload two or more files only the last photo selected will be uploaded in my database. I followed the instructions step-by-step and also used pg as my database. I also managed to successfully mount, serialize, and use an :images column first as a string+serialization and json.

Here's my CRUD functions and proj_params

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(proj_params)
  @project.user_id = @current_user.id if logged_in?
  if @project.save
    flash[:success] = "Project Succesfully Added"
    redirect_to new_project_path
  else
    render 'new'

  end
end

def edit
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  if @project.update_attributes(proj_params)
    flash[:success] = "Project Information Updated"
    redirect_to projects_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  Project.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "Project Entry Deleted"

  redirect_to projects_path
end

private
  def proj_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name,:description, {avatars: []})
end
```

Here's my Project model

My AvatarUploader

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
end
```

Here's the Project Model

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploaders :avatars, AvatarUploader
  serialize :avatars, JSON
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence:true, length:{maximum:150}
  validates :description, presence: true, length:{maximum:1000}
 end
```

The project/new view

```
<%= form_for @project, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages_proj'%> 
  <%= render 'shared/flash_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :pictures %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatars, multiple: true, accept: "image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif, image/png" %>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control cons-txt-area' %>
  <br>

  <%= f.submit "Add Project", class:"btn black" %>

<% end %>
```

[IMAGE 1: I think it's a problem about actually saving it cause it does 2 updates for 2 images uploaded for id = "$1". The params hash contains the names of both of my images so i think the view part works fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcPbh.png)

Comment: Please upload code as text.

Comment: Updated my post with relevant code.